# Unable to fetch value of key from firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

### first.Component.html

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
 <button type="button" routerLink="editlots" class="btn btn-info" style = "font-size: 
         15px; text-align: center; margin:0 auto; display: block;">View Lots
 </button>
</div>
```

### second.component.html

```html
<tr *ngFor="let it of lot$ | async">
 <td> {{it.alias}} </td>
 <td> {{it.area}} </td>
 <td> {{it.price}} </td>
</tr>
```

Here in plats/bigfork/lots , bigfork is a parent key of lots, but i have other keys too which contains the same child as lots with same data. So i want to make a dynamic I'd in place of bigfork, so that i can access the data with respect of particular button of particular I'd which i have clicked.

### second.component.ts

```
this.itemRef = db.list('/plats/bigfork/lots');
this.lot$ = this.itemRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => ({
        key: action.payload.key,
        ...action.payload.val() 
    }));
});
```

> Firebase Database

```
{
"key": "bigfork",
"bg": "Background URL ",
"cover": "https://",
"description": "The conservation",
"footer": {
  "address": "\t\t",
  "companyName": "Companys",
  "email": "user@email.com",
  "favicon": "https:",
  "phone": "111.1111.111",
  "website": "https://www.facebook.com/#"
},
"header": {
  "logo": "https:",
  "title": "Preserve"
},
"lots": [
  {
    "address": "",
    "alias": "113",
    "area": "",
    "assignedTo": "Available",
  },
  {
    "address": "",
    "alias": "112",
    "area": "",
    "assignedTo": "Available",
  }],

  {
 "key": "cdl",
"bg": "Background URL ",
"cover": "https://",
"description": "The conservation",
"footer": {
  "address": "\t\t",
  "companyName": "Companys",
  "email": "user@email.com",
  "favicon": "https:",
  "phone": "111.1111.111",
  "website": "https://www.facebook.com/#"
},
"header": {
  "logo": "https:",
  "title": "Preserve"
},
"lots": [
  {
    "address": "",
    "alias": "113",
    "area": "",
    "assignedTo": "Available",
  },
  {
    "address": "",
    "alias": "112",
    "area": "",
    "assignedTo": "Available",
  }],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a query:

```
this.itemRef = db.list('/plats', ref => ref.orderByChild('lots').equalTo('lots'))
```

This way you can use a value of a child to be able to get the different keys in your database.